# Jvectormap: Задержка перед POST-запросом

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, post

Установила скрипт SVG карты мира jvectorMap версии 1.2.2.

Карта отображается корректно, события обрабатываются нормально, при наведении мышкой на страну в label выпадает обработанный post запросом текст, только вот при быстром проведении мышкой по странам в label подгружается информация о предыдущей стране, [как на картинке](http://eva-tours.ru/images/old/1.jpg), иногда в label перебираются все страны, а затем показывается правильная информация о последней.

Скрипт вызова карты:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#map').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_mill_en',
        color: '#AAAAAA',
        hoverOpacity: 0.5,
        hoverColor: 'black',
        hoverColor: false,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',

       onRegionLabelShow: function(e, el, code){
            $.post("ajax-label-country.php", {code: code},
                function(data){
                    el.html(data);
                }
            )
        },
        onRegionClick: function(e, code){
            $.post("ajax-redirect-url.php", {code: code},
                function(data){
                    parent.location=data;
                }
            );
        }

    });
});
```

</script>

карта отображается в поле div:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 700px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы значение code не передавалось в post-запрос при быстром перемещении мышью?

задержка

```
function(data){
setTimeout(function(){el.html(data)},500);
}
```

не срабатывает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что элемент label видимо один и вы проводя быстро мышью посылаете множество запросов, 
заведите переменную Label_xhr и в случае ее ненулевого значения, делайте xhr.abort() прежде чем сделать новый запрос:

```
$(function(){
    var Label_xhr;
    $('#map').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_mill_en',
        color: '#AAAAAA',
        hoverOpacity: 0.5,
        hoverColor: 'black',
        hoverColor: false,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',

       onRegionLabelShow: function(e, el, code){
            if (Label_xhr) Label_xhr.abort();
            Label_xhr=$.post("ajax-label-country.php", {code: code},
                function(data){
                    el.html(data);
                }
            )
        },
        onRegionClick: function(e, code){
            $.post("ajax-redirect-url.php", {code: code},
                function(data){
                    parent.location=data;
                }
            );
        }

    });
});
```

ещё один вариант, сделать задержку перед тем как послать запрос и сбрасывать ее в случае повторной попытки запроса (лучше комбинировать с предыдущим решением):

```
$(function () {
    var LabelXhr;
    var LabelTimeout;
    $('#map').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_mill_en',
        color: '#AAAAAA',
        hoverOpacity: 0.5,
        hoverColor: false,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',

        onRegionLabelShow: function (e, el, code) {
            if (Label_xhr) LabelXhr.abort();
            clearTimeout(LabelTimeout);
            LabelTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                LabelTimeout=null;
                LabelXhr = $.post("ajax-label-country.php", {
                    code: code
                },

                function (data) {
                    el.html(data);
                });
            }, 100);
        },
        onRegionClick: function (e, code) {
            $.post("ajax-redirect-url.php", {
                code: code
            },

            function (data) {
                parent.location = data;
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо :)

Comment: прочитайте второе решение, оно немного более оптимально.

Comment: Во втором варианте в label ничего не высвечивается.

Comment: странно, мож пропустил чего, в общем должно работать конечно... тут уже я не увижу в чем дело без прямого доступа :) но если у вас там посещаемость не гигантская, то сойдет и первый.

Comment: все работает великолепно!